# Creating object containers for single and multiple objects

Tags: java, collections, iterable

I'm designing a class which has a purpose of being an ***immutable*** container for some objects. It happens very often that the `Container` object is holding just a single object and since it's immutable, I tend to implement it as follows:

```
public abstract class Container{

    public abstract Iterable<Object> getObjectGroup();

    private Container(){ }

    public static Container createSingle(final Object o) {
        return new Container() {

            @Override
            public Iterable<Object> getObjectGroup() {
                return new Iterable<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
                        return new Iterator<Object>() {

                            private boolean next = true;

                            @Override
                            public boolean hasNext() {
                                return next;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public Object next() {
                                next = false;
                                return o;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void remove() {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unable to remove from an immutable container");
                            }
                        };
                    }
                };
            }
        };  
    }

    public static Container createMultiple(final Collection<Object> o) {
        return new Container() {

            @Override
            public Iterable<Object> getObjectGroup() {
                return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(o);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

***QUESTION:*** Is it actually justified to make such a distinction between containers for single and multiple objects. I primiraly do this in order to not waste the memory for creating a specific collection object like `ArrayList<T>` or `TreeSet<T>` which is definitely redundant in case of a single-object `Container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no absolute answer to this question: Whether the distinction between a uni-object container and a multi-object container is justified depends totally on the context of your problem.

I would say that unless you already know that you are running into memory issues **and that the memory issue is caused by these collections**, it is a premature optimization that just adds complexity. And even if you are running into performance issues, there is likely something better to optimize than this code.

So the answer should probably be the same as it is to every other question of form "Should I increase complexity to optimize time/memory usage": Not unless it is a problem.

Comment: Reasonable, actually. Thanks much.